Optimal Betting Strategy, where the price of a stock price is the sum of 3 iid X~U(1,13)
This is practice for a market making game.
Suppose that the price of a stock is given by the sum of 3 i.i.d. uniform discrete random variables with values 1–13. Right now, I have the option to buy the stock for $15 before the drawing occurs.
With an initial bankroll of $1000, how many shares should I buy?
My Work:
The expected value (EV) of $X$ is $\frac{1+13}{2} = 7$, and for 3 random variables, it would thus be $7 \times 3 = 21$. This leaves us with a spread of $21 - 15 = 6$. Since we are "investing" $15$ per share, the EV per dollar invested would be $\frac{6}{15} = 0.4$.
The lowest price the stock can come out to is 3 (if all 3 random variables equal 1). This means my maximum loss is $15 - 3 = 12$. I can "manufacture" a bet with odds of $6:12$, where I make $6$ if I win and lose $12$ if I lose. This simplifies down to $1:2$, which is equivalent to $0.5:1$.
Applying this into the Kelly criterion formula, I get:
$$
f = \frac{\text{EV}}{1 - \text{book odds}} = \frac{0.4}{1 - 0.5} = \frac{0.4}{0.5} = 0.8.
$$
Thus, the Kelly criterion suggests betting 80%. This number seems quite high, and I was wondering if my calculation is correct.

The Kelly criterion is for a bet between two single valued outcomes, while here there are $37$ possible outcomes, so this needs a more sophisticated analysis.

What is your Utility Function?  That is, how can you determine which of two strategies is preferable (other than in the case where one strategy simply dominates the other in all scenarios)?  What are the other available investments?

No utility function and not enough time to calculate all of the EVs, this is just a rough estimate.

I came up with a solution. This is not an empirical solution, but a quick way to estimate the Kelly criterion and determine the optimal bet size. During this interview, you have only a few minutes (<3) to answer this question, hence the need for fast estimations.
Solution:
We know that the expected value of a single random variable is given by:
$E[X] = \frac{1+13}{2} = 7$
Thus, the expected value of the sum of three independent random variables would be:
$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3} X_i\right) = 3 \times 7 = 21$
Next, we calculate the variance of a single random variable:
$\text{Var}(X) = \frac{(13-1)^2}{12} = 12$
So, the variance of the sum of three such random variables is:
$\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3} X_i\right) = 3 \times 12 = 36$
This gives us a standard deviation of:
$\sigma = \sqrt{36} = 6$
Since the initial price is $\$15$, it is one standard deviation away from the mean, as:
$21 - 6 = 15$
Therefore, the probability of making money on this trade can be estimated as:
$\text{Probability of profit} \approx 50\% + 35\% = 85\%$
This approximation comes from the empirical rule, where about 34% of the distribution lies within one standard deviation above the mean.
We estimate the average expected profit as roughly:
$E(\text{profit}) \approx 21 - 15 = 6 \quad$
although the real expected profit would be slightly higher.
Estimating Expected Loss
We can estimate the expected loss as a uniform random variable from $15 to two standard deviations away from the mean, to avoid outliers. This gives us:
$21 - 2\sigma = 21 - 12 = 9$
Thus, we have:
$X_{\text{estimate}} \sim U(9, 15)$
The mean of this uniform distribution is:
$E(X_{\text{estimate}}) = \frac{9 + 15}{2} = 12$
Hence, the average expected loss is approximately:
$E(\text{loss}) \approx 15 - 12 = 3 \quad$
Applying the Kelly Criterion
The Kelly formula is given by:
$f = \frac{(p \cdot \text{expected profit}) - ((1 - p) \cdot \text{expected loss})}{\text{expected profit}}$
Plugging in the values:
$f = \frac{(0.85 \times 6) - (0.15 \times 3)}{6} = \frac{5.1 - 0.45}{6} \approx 0.80$
Thus, the Kelly criterion suggests that we should bet around 80% of our bankroll, which is approximately $800. This would allow us to buy around 50-55 shares.
Note:
I realize that this estimation is not perfect. The Kelly criterion used here does not properly account for position size; it only gauges the risk. You would need to adjust the loss per share to refine the calculation. However, I believe it provides a reasonable estimate in a short amount of time.
Please let me know if there are any errors or further refinements that could be made.
